# Company Community Contact Question

Tags: community

I am trying to upload contacts to a Company Community User however I am receiving an error stating that "Owner ID: id value of incorrect type:" I've verified that is the correct contactid. Thoughts? Thanks !

Comment: Does the value you are setting for the owner ID start with `005` if not then that would be the cause of the message. An Owner has to be a user

Comment: Eric I was missing the additional 0 at the beginning. It's always the little things. Thanks !!

Comment: Great, making it an answer then. Please accept so the question can be closed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the value you are setting for the owner ID start with 005 if not then that would be the cause of the message. An Owner has to be a user